# How do I group by and aggregate orgtable more efficiently?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have the following org table where I actively record columns 1,2,3,4 and the remaining columns are calculated from the first four. Using this I calculate the aggregate from the last three columns using `orgaggregate` [link](https://github.com/tbanel/orgaggregate).

MWE

```
#+TITLE: Workout

#+NAME: helpers
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun k/get-week (org-date-time)
  (set 'year (nth 5 (org-parse-time-string org-date-time)))
  (set 'month (nth 4 (org-parse-time-string org-date-time)))
  (set 'day (nth 3 (org-parse-time-string org-date-time)))
  (car
   (calendar-iso-from-absolute
    (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
     (list month day year)))))
#+end_src

* Horizontal Push
#+NAME: hpush
| date             | progression | sets-reps | comment                               | year | week-number | total-volume |
|------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+------+-------------+--------------|
| <2021-11-26 Fri> | push up     | 5 5 5 5 5 | Hard on wrists                        | 2021 |          47 |           25 |
| <2021-11-30 Tue> | push up     | 8 8 8 8 8 | Parallettes                           | 2021 |          48 |           40 |
| <2021-12-03 Fri> | push up     | 8 8 8 8 8 | parallettes inclined                  | 2021 |          48 |           40 |
| <2021-12-06 Mon> | push up     | 3 3 3 3 4 | parallettes parallel                  | 2021 |          49 |           16 |
| <2022-01-03 Mon> | push up     | 5 5 5     | parallettes parallel right difficulty | 2022 |           1 |           15 |
#+TBLFM: $7='(reduce '+ (mapcar 'string-to-number (split-string $3 " ")))
#+TBLFM: $5='(nth 5 (org-parse-time-string $1))
#+TBLFM: $6='(k/get-week $1)

#+BEGIN: aggregate :table "hpush" :cols "'year' 'week-number' sum('total-volume')"
| 'year' | 'week-number' | sum('total-volume') |
|--------+---------------+---------------------|
|   2021 |            47 |                  25 |
|   2021 |            48 |                  80 |
|   2021 |            49 |                  16 |
|   2022 |             1 |                  15 |
#+END:

# Local Variables:
# org-confirm-babel-evaluate: nil
# eval: (progn (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "helpers") (org-babel-execute-src-block) (outline-hide-sublevels 1))
# End:
```

I would like to record only columns `date, progression, sets-reps, comment` in the first table and not calculate the remaining columns in the first table but create a second table (using the first table's 4 columns) which will have `year, week-number, sum(total-volume)`.

With SQL, I'd roughly be doing this

```sql
select to_year(date), get_week_number(date), sum(sets-reps)
from table
group by to_year(date), get_week_number(date);
```

I'm trying to get weekly volume of my reps.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: +1 for showing the SQL query.

Comment: @Drew thank you for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with sqlite and python. I still can't figure out a elisp method.

#### Sqlite

```
#+begin_src sqlite :db /tmp/workout.db :var workout=hpush :colnames yes
drop table if exists workout;
create table workout(date text, progression text, set_rep text, comment text, year text, week text, vol text);
.mode csv
.import $workout workout
with recursive split(date, set_rep, str) AS (
select date, '', set_rep||' ' from workout
union all select
date,
substr(str, 0, instr(str, ' ')),
substr(str, instr(str, ' ')+1)
from split where str != ''
)
select
strftime('%Y', substr(date, 2, 10)) year,
strftime('%W', substr(date, 2, 10)) week,
sum(set_rep) as total_volume
from split
where set_rep != ''
group by year, week
;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| year | week | total_volume |
|------+------+--------------|
| 2021 |   47 |           25 |
| 2021 |   48 |           80 |
| 2021 |   49 |           16 |
| 2022 |    1 |           15 |
```

#### Python

```
#+NAME: pyhelper
#+begin_src python :var tbl=None
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
parse_date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "<%Y-%m-%d %a>")
get_week = lambda x: parse_date(x).strftime("%W")
get_year = lambda x: parse_date(x).strftime("%Y")
sum_reps = lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x).split()))

final = defaultdict(int)
for item in tbl:
    year = get_year(item[0])
    reps = sum_reps(item[2])
    week = get_week(item[0])
    final[f'{year}_{week}'] += reps
res = [[key, val] for key, val in final.items()]
return res
#+end_src

#+CALL: pyhelper(tbl=hpush)

#+RESULTS:
| 2021_47 | 25 |
| 2021_48 | 80 |
| 2021_49 | 16 |
| 2022_01 | 15 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may shrink those annoying columns to zero width:

```
#+NAME: hpush
| date             | progression | sets-reps | comment                               |…|…|…|
|                  |             |           |                                       |…|…|…|
|------------------+-------------+-----------+---------------------------------------+…+…+…+
| <2021-11-26 Fri> | push up     | 5 5 5 5 5 | Hard on wrists                        |…|…|…|
| <2021-11-30 Tue> | push up     | 8 8 8 8 8 | Parallettes                           |…|…|…|
| <2021-12-03 Fri> | push up     | 8 8 8 8 8 | parallettes inclined                  |…|…|…|
| <2021-12-06 Mon> | push up     | 3 3 3 3 4 | parallettes parallel                  |…|…|…|
| <2022-01-03 Mon> | push up     | 5 5 5     | parallettes parallel right difficulty |…|…|…|
#+TBLFM: $7='(reduce '+ (mapcar 'string-to-number (split-string $3 " ")))
#+TBLFM: $5='(nth 5 (org-parse-time-string $1))
#+TBLFM: $6='(k/get-week $1)
```

To do so, add width cookies, for example in the second row: `<0>`

```
... | year | week-number | total-volume |
... |  <0> |         <0> |          <0> |
... +------+-------------+--------------|
... | 2021 |          47 |           25 |
... | 2021 |          48 |           40 |
... | 2021 |          48 |           40 |
... | 2021 |          49 |           16 |
... | 2022 |           1 |           15 |
```

And then type `C-u C-c Tab` in the table to shrink columns.
Type `C-u C-u C-c Tab` to get back full width.

Comment: sorry I don't understand how your answer answers my question. I did not ask about shrinking columns

Comment: Sure.  
  
You have a working solution, but with those 3 additional columns you don't want to see.  
  
My suggestion was to stick with your solution, but get those 3 columns out of sight.